# Dotfuscator: Couldn't find Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dotfuscator

`Dotfuscator` was working fine until today. I cannot figure out why.

My project type is aspnetcore 3.0. Publish using the following command:

`dotnet publish --self-contained -c Release -r linux-x64`

The error output is:

```
  [Build Output] Renaming...
  [Build Output]
  [Build Output] Updating Markup...
  [Build Output]
  [Build Output] Writing map file to C:\code\quant\Dotfuscated\Map_win.xml
  [Build Output]
  [Smart Obfuscation] User Type QuantWS.Startup was excluded from renaming by AspNetStartupRule for the following reasons: Type is an ASP.NET Core Startup Type.
  [Build Output] Writing Assemblies...
  [Build Output]
  [Build Output] Couldn't load external type because its assembly can't be found: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

  === Pre-bind state information ===
  C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\QuantWS.dll
  LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
  LOG: Appbase = C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64
  LOG: Processing DEVPATH.
  LOG: DEVPATH not enabled. Falling through to regular bind.
  LOG: Checking Cache
  LOG: Assembly not found in cache.
  LOG: Codebase not set.
  LOG: Processing CodeBase
  LOG: Checking Windows Kit Folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd       LOG: Not found in Windows Kit Folder.
  LOG: Checking Windows Kit Folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Checking Windows Kit Folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Checking Windows Kit Folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Checking Windows Kit Folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\3.0.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Not found in Windows Kit Folder.
  LOG: Checking AssemblyFoldersEx paths for runtime version v4.0.30319.
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Not Found in AssemblyFoldersEx paths.
  LOG: Checking AssemblyFolders paths.
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Not Found in AssemblyFolders paths.
  LOG: Checking Visual Studio AssemblyFolders paths.
  LOG: Not Found in Visual Studio AssemblyFolders paths.
  LOG: Looking in GAC
  LOG: Assembly not found in GAC
  LOG: Probing AppBase
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.winmd
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Strong name match failed
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll.deploy
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll.deploy
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.exe
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.exe
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.exe.deploy
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.exe.deploy
  LOG: Probing Private Bin Path
  LOG: Bin Path not set
  LOG: Processing User Defined Assembly Load Path.
  LOG: The User Defined Assembly Load Path is not set.
  LOG: Checking Reference Assemblies folders.
  LOG: Not found in Reference Assemblies folders.
  LOG: Checking NuGet Folder : C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Strong name match failed
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Checking NuGet Folder : C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Strong name match failed
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Checking NuGet Folder : C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.app.runtime.linux-x64\3.0.0-preview7.19365.7\runtimes\linux-x64\lib\netcoreapp3.0
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.app.runtime.linux-x64\3.0.0-preview7.19365.7\runtimes\linux-x64\lib\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Strong name match failed
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.app.runtime.linux-x64\3.0.0-preview7.19365.7\runtimes\linux-x64\lib\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.app.runtime.linux-x64\3.0.0-preview7.19365.7\runtimes\linux-x64\lib\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll   LOG: Checking NuGet Folder : C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Strong name match failed
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Checking NuGet Folder : C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Strong name match failed
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.ni.dll
  LOG: Not found in NuGet folders.
  LOG: Checking additional folder : C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64
  LOG: Probing C:\code\quant\QuantWS\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\linux-x64\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Strong name match failed
  LOG: Checking additional folder : C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~QuantWS.8
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~QuantWS.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Probing C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\~QuantWS.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
  LOG: Not found in additional folders.
  LOG: Loose binding enabled.  Probing for later versions.
```

When I look up `IWebHostBuilder` in Visual Studio, it is in
`C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\3.0.0-preview7.19365.7\ref\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll`. The same file is also in the publish output directory. But Dotfuscator just cannot accept them and says `Strong name match failed`.

It was all right until today. If I downgrade the project to aspnetcore 2.2, the problems will be gone. Can anybody help?

Comment: How are you calling Dotfuscator? Did you modify your `.csproj`, and if so, what were the changes?

Comment: @JoeSewell yes I added a PostBuildEvent exec command: if $(ConfigurationName) == Release dotfuscatorCLI ..\Dotfuscator_win.xml /in:$(TargetPath),-$(TargetDir)\lib.dll /out:$(OutDir)\obfuscated

Comment: It sounds like you're using Dotfuscator Community (a.k.a. CE). Try adding the directory you found (`C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\...`) as an [assembly load path](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_settings.html#pctoc-assembly-load-paths-tab). (I should note at this point that I'm a developer for the Dotfuscator team, and am acting on my company's behalf here.)

Comment: @JoeSewell Yes I am using CE. Adding the assembly load path does the obfuscation. Still not sure if it works. Why doesn't Dotfuscator accept the assembly in the output dir? I'm publishing a Linux version but the assembly load path now points to the windows version.

Comment: @mugi Reference assemblies are not platform specific and Dotfuscator just needs access to the reference assembly to verify signatures, so that should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note*: I am answering in my professional capacity as an employee of the developer of Dotfuscator

Dotfuscator automatically attempts to locate reference assemblies in locations it knows about, but Microsoft has recently added some new ones (.NETCore 3.0 is a preview after all!). Future Community updates will add this new location which will address this automatically, but for now the correct workaround is to manually add the new location to Assembly Load Paths (which you have already done).

The issue with loading the copy of the assembly in the publish folder appears to be due to an issue with the Full Framework processing non-Windows assemblies, this limitation should be addressed in future Dotfuscator updates.

Comment: `The issue with loading the copy of the assembly in the publish folder appears to be due to an issue with the Full Framework processing non-Windows assemblies` Could you tell me more about this? I found the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll` in the publish folder is of the same version but different file size. Maybe it is platform specific to some extent?